# Sending email using php & mysql data in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send an email by using a select statement which gives me rows that shows me the duedate and customer_notified_dt and name and email, so I created a model wrote the function,

```
public function getInvoicesForNotification(){

            $query = ' 
                    SELECT a.Fullname, a.Email, b.duedate, b.customer_notified_dt 
                    FROM invoice b
                    left outer join userinfo a
                    on a.Owner = b.payor_orig_id and a.UPDATE_DT is null
                    where  
                    b.UPDATE_DT is null and b.customer_notified_dt is null
                    having   sum(b.gross_amount + b.type_related_amount) > sum(b.gross_paid + b.type_related_paid); ';

            $query = $this->db->query($query);
            $result = $query->result();
            return $result; 
}
```

So in my controller I have a function which receives this data and should directly send an email when this function in the controller is called and is written like this,

```
public function sendEmailforUnpaidInvoice() {
    //fetch tha data from the database 
    $this->load->model('invoice_page');
    $foo = $this->invoice_page->getInvoicesForNotification();
    $foo1 = json_decode(json_encode($foo[0]), true);    
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from('masnad@loaners.club', 'Masnad');
    $this->email->to($foo1['Email']); 
    $this->email->subject('Pay Payments');
    $this->email->message('Your due date for payment is'+ $foo1['duedate']);    
    $this->email->send();


    if (/*not sure what to return*/) {
       alert("email failed to send");
    } else {
      $uptArray = array('customer_notified_dt' => NOW());
      $this -> db -> update('invoice', $uptArray);     

       }

}
```

So what it needs to do is send the email when this function is called, write the due date in the email body, and after email is sent change the customer_notified_dt from null to current date. I need to even use a foreach to load all the tables if there is more.
The query looks okay since its working but I think I have several mistakes in the controller so need help fixing it.

Comment: You are mixing mysql and CI in your code!!!

Comment: @Saty I saw a example somewhere so I thought that might be the way, do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: @Saty I tried changing the codes, but ofcourse I am not sure how to load all the rows and put them in the controller.